# Stop GIMP from intersecting same-direction shapes within one path

Tags: gimp, text, path, selections

There is a line of text I`d like to transform as a path and then convert to a selection to perform an effect: [image]
The font I use makes letter intersections inevitable.
The intersections between letters are outside the resulting selection.

The method I use now is Path → Path To Selection. What do I need to do to convert properly?
The version of GIMP I use is 2.10.24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known "problem". The solution is to use the [`ofn-text-path-selection` plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/). For instance
with a path like this:

[image]

The regular selection renders like this:

[image]

And the plugin instead gives you a selection that renders like this:

[image]

The problem wasn't [so trivial](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Overlapping-Paths)

Comment: Do you know if there is a report for that in the issue tracker? I couldn't find one yet.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Not as far as I know. But I don't think that you can fix the current behavior without breaking things, you would really need an additional function. If you want I can make a report and expound my algorithm.

Comment: This would definitely be beneficial - it doesn't do any good to label something as a known problem and not tell the developers of the software about it :)

Comment: "Problem" is a big word. I have always seen behave like this since at least 2.4...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the script mentioned by Xenoid, another possibility would be to type the text in Inkscape, convert to outlines, ungroup, do a Union boolean operation, save the SVG, and import into GIMP as a path.

Example showing Inkscape generated paths (top) imported and GIMP generated path (bottom)

[image]

Also, what kind of effect are you trying to create that would require paths in the first place?  It might simply be easier to use a vector image editor such as Inkscape. For example, text along a path is much easier, and text doesn't even need to be converted to outlines first in Inkscape.